# A die is thrown 10 times.Find the probability that the number of sixes obtained is between 3 and 5 inclusive.

Tags: probability

I have not understand the question. Can you help me please. I search for answers in the bool Imran Amiran even though i have not been able to proceed. Help me please. THANK YOU.

Comment: the probability that you get no sixes is $\left( \frac 56 \right)^{10}$, can you see why?  Now can you compute the probability of getting exactly one $6$?  Exactly two sixes?  And so on...

Comment: Check your book for a section about binomial distributions.  Another term to look for in the index is Bernoulli trial, but I'm not familiar with your specific text.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=3}^{5}\binom{10}{n}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{10-n}$

Answer (score 1):

Split it into **disjoint** events, and then add up their probabilities:

- The probability of getting exactly $\color\red3$ sixes out of $10$ rolls is $\binom{10}{\color\red3}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red3}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{10-\color\red3}$
- The probability of getting exactly $\color\red4$ sixes out of $10$ rolls is $\binom{10}{\color\red4}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red4}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{10-\color\red4}$
- The probability of getting exactly $\color\red5$ sixes out of $10$ rolls is $\binom{10}{\color\red5}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red5}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{10-\color\red5}$

---

Hence the probability of getting $3$ to $5$ sixes out of $10$ rolls is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=3}^{5}\binom{10}{n}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{10-n}$$